# Changing the fontsize of the words in the shkactionsheet

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook, sharekit

I would like to change the font size of the words displayed in the shkactionsheet. I am not sure how to change the font size.

the word looks like:

```
+ (SHKActionSheet *)actionSheetForType:(SHKShareType)type
{
    SHKActionSheet *as = [[SHKCONFIG(SHKActionSheetSubclass) alloc] initWithTitle:SHKLocalizedString(@"Share ")
                                                      delegate:nil
                                             cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                        destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
    as.delegate = as;
    as.item = [[[SHKItem alloc] init] autorelease];
    as.item.shareType = type;

    as.sharers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
    NSArray *favoriteSharers = [SHK favoriteSharersForType:type];

    // Add buttons for each favorite sharer
    id class;
    for(NSString *sharerId in favoriteSharers)
    {
        class = NSClassFromString(sharerId);
        if ([class canShare])
        {
            [as addButtonWithTitle: [class sharerTitle] ];
            [as.sharers addObject:sharerId];
        }
    }

    if([SHKCONFIG(showActionSheetMoreButton) boolValue])
    {
        // Add More button
        [as addButtonWithTitle:SHKLocalizedString(@"More...")];
    }

    // Add Cancel button
    [as addButtonWithTitle:SHKLocalizedString(@"Cancel")];
    as.cancelButtonIndex = as.numberOfButtons -1;

    return [as autorelease];
}
```

Comment: it seems that you can't change the font size of the share text. I have been trying since just now.. Any way u can change the size?

Answer (score 0):

SHKActionSheet is a subclass of UIActionSheet. So check documentation of UIActionSheet. If I remember well, it is not possible to change font. However, you can create your own UIView and mimic UIActionSheet interface with your customizations.